# Does Thyristor (SCR ) works for Inrush current protection?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, power-electronics, thyristor, inrush-current

Does  a SCR ie  Thyristor work for Inrush current protection in a circuit ?

Comment: If the ratings are appropriate then it should.

Comment: No. There are specific inrush current limiters (CL) which have a high resistance to start, then a very low resistance after they heat up.

Comment: Post a schematic of what you have in mind, please.

Comment: It could potentially be used to limit AC inrush similar to a light dimmer. But I don't see how it would be useful for limiting DC inrush. Once it turns on, it is going to stay on until the current drops to zero.

Answer (score 1):

I first saw a SCR employed to bypass some 5W wirewound green phillips resistors on the DC side of the mains bridge rectifier on a NZ designed SMPS in 1985 .The idea is that the resisters limited starting current charging the Phillips pcb mount        220 microfarad    385VDC elteclytic bus cap reasonably slowly .When the converter chip booted up the SCR turned on wasting about 1 Volt which was much better than just the resisters .Normal cheap TO220  SCRs do not have very good surge current ratings so reliability is not good where power quality is bad .A relay will waste less power and be more robust under surge conditions .30 years later I saw a triac on the AC side in a chinese imported SMPS .The AC Triac has the same shortcomings as the DC SCR .

Answer (score 1):

> Does a SCR ie Thyristor work for Inrush current protection in a circuit ?

Yes it does. To limit inrush you need two things

1) something to limit current (higher resistance).
2) something to bypass the limiter (lower resistance).

Now an NTC thermistor does satisfy these needs as its resistance starts off high and then decreases. However... sometimes this isn't suitable, sometimes a bit more control is needed. In such circumstances a controllable switch is needed and equally means to drive and means to control.

In such circumstances an SCR can be used, like a MOSFET, BJT, IGBT or a relay. It really comes down to operating needs.

One advantage of an SCR is they do have lower on-state losses at higher power. However... they do need to be continually stimulated if there isn't a constant forward current load.

Essentially what is required is means to monitor the DClink voltage, some "control" to inhibit gate current when the voltage is below a threshold and then some means to provide gate current when the voltage is above a threshold.

This threshold is usually governed by the peak inrush current you are permitted to draw. Below are two schemes. Both have a resistor to trickle-charge the main DClink capacitor. The 1st relies on additional DClink monitoring to then send a pulse chain to a pulse transformer to permit gating.

The 2nd derives the threshold via a crude voltage divider and then relies on zener current to gate the SCR.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is one specific circumstance (1) where a thyristor, properly used, could protect from inrush.

However, what's usually needed from an inrush protector, high resistance to start with, dropping to low resistance later, is not what a thyristor does. An [NTC thermistor](https://en.tdk.eu/download/528070/f5be4fca9d1f66204de9cf37891e5265/pdf-inrushcurrentlimiting-an2.pdf) is the usual choice, if you're looking for a generally applicable single component.

Alternatives in specific circumstances are a series resistor with a timed relay to short it, and 'soft-start' programming on power supply converters.

(1) Switching a transformer on at the peak of a mains cycle eliminates transformer saturation inrush. There are many ZVS (zero voltage switching) devices, which reduce EMI with a normal load by switching at the voltage minimum. With a transformer load however, ZVS guarantees maximum inrush current.