# Using thermistor vs. soft starter for motor

Tags: dc-motor, thermistor, inrush-current, ac-motor

What is the advantage that complex soft starters give over NTC thermistors if one is only trying to get rid of inrush current spikes?

Answer (score 1):

A VFD is a complex soft starter for Motors that limits acceleration and current and thus RPM rate of change with source frequency with constant V/F with high efficiency  . A huge NTC must get hot to operate and thus start at reduced current. The amount of power determines the best method. There are many more examples.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage a "complex soft starter" provides  like the one describe here [Does Thyristor (SCR ) works for Inrush current protection?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/378907/does-thyristor-scr-works-for-inrush-current-protection/378957#378957)  is when a unit is subjected to repeated inrush events in a short period of time.

An NTC is good if the likelihood of "fast" restart or intermittent power outage is low.

If you were to use an NTC and there was a blackout on the supply, you are restricted to the thermal time constant of the NTC to realise a repeatable management of the inrush current.

Answer (score 0):

**NTC**:

- Pros: cheap, only one component in the BOM, a few tests to find the correct value for you application.
- Cons: Waste of energy because of small residual resistance when hot, Get hot. In a nutshell resistor is always "there". Should be cold to be efficient, so it will not always have the same effect on inrush currents depending on its temperature making it not a robust solution. Not ideal for high power solution.

**Inrush current limiter chip**:

- Pros: Behave always the same way thanks to current limitation (through shunt resistor or using the Rds,on of the MOSFET) so it's a robust way to do it. The chip complexity often allow more functions like timed overcurrent detection, UVLO, short circuit protection (act like a very fast fuse. Example: the LTC7000 can cut power in 70ns if current is above a threshold).
- Cons: Chip could be expensive (several dollars), a lot of components in the BOM, some chips are complex to understand and thus you will have to fully test it for industrial purpose.

My opinion: all the functions offered by those chips make me prefer them compared to NTC. But it is up to you to design a solution without the need of reliability and high level of safety (for a personal project or a low power product for example).